# How to recover deleted orphaned assets in Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, data-analysis, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

As part of my Cleanup activity I have deleted the Quicksight user without transferring the ownership to another user and where deleted including all orphaned resources.

Can you please help me recovery all the resources.

Tried with Restoreanalysis as well but it doesn't recover the deleted resources

Thanks in Advance

want to recover all the deleted orphaned resources in AWS Quicksight.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to list out these resources using the aws-cli and re-attach those assets to another user or group. See https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/quicksight/index.html for more information.